# how to prevent bootstrap navbar from collapsing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

am using https://demo.uifort.com which uses bootstrap 4.I have a navbar with icons.[image]

on smaller devices the navbar collapses and what i get is
[image]

what i want to achieve is the icons to remain as they are on the desktop.
here is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-secondary p-3 shadow-sm fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-40 bg-white rounded-circle text-center" href="#" id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo2.png" class="d-inline-block my-auto" width="26px">
           Crypto Dashboard
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler is-active collapsed hamburger hamburger--elastic" type="button"
                data-target="#wrapper" aria-controls="nav-second"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" id="but">
                    <span class="hamburger-box">
                        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                    </span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-second">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto mt-lg-0 mt-3 px-lg-0 px-3 py-3 py-md-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-link-icon" href="#">
                        <i class="far fa-bell"></i>
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger count-notif" >5</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-link-icon" href="#">
                        <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger count-notif">5</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-link-icon dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbar-default_dropdown_1"
                       role="button"
                       data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbar-default_dropdown_1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            <i class="far fa-user"></i>
                            profile
                        </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                            Messages
                        </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            <i class="far fa-bell"></i>
                            Notifications
                        </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                            Settings
                        </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
                            Logout
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

</nav>
```

so how can i prevent the navbar from collapsing on smaller devices and icons to remain as they are

Comment: You need to post the CSS file you use. There is somewhere `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1000px)` or similar, where you can define at which screen size the navbar should close (collapse).

Comment: Can you create [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to show us your case?